# HTML block page even when directly opened

Tags: html, security, iis-8

Hello I am making my own webpage, its in html.

Now my question is that i have an media.html page that is in an speparate folder called protection.

by the menu entry i have it routes trough a java script to promt for a password.
After the correct password is put in it will route you to the page in the protection folder.

But when you put in the direct link to the page https://domain.nl/protection/media.html (left out the real domain).
the page is loaded without asking for a password.

the script

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--hide
var password=prompt('Enter the password:','');
var mypassword="2Wsxxsw2";
if (password==mypassword)
{
  window.location="/protection/media.html";
}
else
{
 window.location="/protection/mediaUP.html";
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

is there a way to protect the page even when you go to the direct file.

It runs on an server 2012 R2 IS 8.5 web server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Perform the authorization check **on the server** (i.e. to not use client side JavaScript for this)
2. Perform the authorization check for every page that requires authorization

Your current approach is effectively to throw a tarpaulin over the door to your secret room and stand a bloke outside holding a clipboard with instructions to him which say "If anyone says 2Wsxxsw2, point them under the tarp" (and anyone can look over his shoulder to read the clipboard).

Comment: the script it slef pops up a massage box and the page code doenst acept to show the code at that point.

but i will check the ahuthorisation check server side

Comment: "the script it slef pops up a massage box and the page code doenst acept to show the code at that point" — It takes me about 5 seconds to turn JS off and stop the JS from running at all.

Comment: that wasnt what i meant but i will take a look at iis and try to lock the folder with authentication.

Comment: i just setup basic auth in iis manager on the folder and now it justs asks for my credentials. and that was what i needed because this is an protected page when you browse to it directly but if i place an menu button on top of my page that links to the same folder and htl file it just loads the page without asking for credentials

Comment: @Sojab0on — Presumably that is because *you have already entered them* and have not closed your browser (the entire browser, not just all the tabs) to wipe them from its memory since.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but not with JavaScript. In your example I can just open source of page and see password and correct URL.

You can protect this folder by web server settings. I'm not expert in IS but I think there is not problem. Just search how protect folder in IS web server.

Comment: just setup basic auth in iis manager on the folder and now it justs asks for my credentials. and that was what i needed because this is an protected page when you browse to it directly but if i place an menu button on top of my page that links to the same folder and html file it just loads the page without asking for credentials

Comment: @Sojab0on basic auth ask login and password each time when you load pages. But usually web browsers  remember credentials and not ask it each time. In browsers is checkbox 'remember password' for this. For check you should close your browser and open it again - in must ask password.